# Fastlane screengrab not reading config

Tags: android, screenshot, fastlane

I'm starting to use screengrab to make automated screenshots of my app. I've a question regarding the "config" file named "Appfile".

Here is content:

```
json_key_file "" # Path to the json secret file - Follow https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/#setup to get one

app_package_name 'be.example.android.app'

app_apk_path 'app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/APP-DEV-debug-0.9.0.apk'
tests_apk_path 'app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/dev/debug/app-dev-debug-androidTest.apk'

locales ['en-US', 'fr-FR']

clear_previous_screenshots true
```

When I execute fastlane, errors are displayed and it seems fastlane is not able to understand Appfile.

```
git:(develop) ✗ fastlane screengrab
[12:02:58]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile
undefined method `app_package_name' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x007f81cf463220>
undefined method `app_package_name' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x007f81cf42b320>
undefined method `app_package_name' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x007f81cf418fe0>
[12:03:01]: To not be asked about this value, you can specify it using 'app_package_name'
[12:03:01]: The package name of the app under test (e.g. com.yourcompany.yourapp): ^Cundefined method `app_package_name' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x007f81cf30ba80>
undefined method `app_package_name' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x007f81cf2f9538>
```

Does anyone have an idea what I do wrong ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, the config file is no longer called "Appfile" but "Screengrabfile" now...